# Cannot adjust UIScrollView with UITabbar

Tags: swift5, xcode10.2

i'm trying to setup a uiscrollview on a uinavigationbar and uitabbar controllers, the uiscrollview is limited to the bottom of the main view

i tried to rewrite all of the constraints, and i've tried to add constant for the bottom constraint

```
// these are the constraints for the items inside the contentView 

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            mainImg.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            mainImg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            mainImg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateView.topAnchor),


            dateView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImg.bottomAnchor),
            dateView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            dateView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            dateView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),

            calenderIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            calenderIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            calenderIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateView.centerYAnchor),

            dateLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calenderIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            dateLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateView.centerYAnchor),

            titleLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateView.bottomAnchor, constant: 18),
            titleLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            titleLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),

            articalLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            articalLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 26),
            articalLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -26),
            articalLbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100),
            articalLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 150)


        ])
```

```
// this is the setup function for the scrollview

func setupScrollView(){
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)


        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
```

[image: screenshot]